# ruby: avoid duplicate method in genertors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

I'm having trouble to avoid duplicate code in my generators. I have tried to use concerns but without success. Can anyone help me ?

My 3 generators are having the same method called :

```
# Initialize the generator accepting attributes as arguments  
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    super
    @attributes = []
    model_attributes.each do |attribute|
      @attributes << Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new(*attribute.split(":")) if attribute.include?(":")
    end
  end
```

So I have created in `lib/generators/concerns` a file called `initializer.rb`

```
module Initializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Initialize the generator accepting attributes as arguments  
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    super
    @attributes = []
    model_attributes.each do |attribute|
      @attributes << Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new(*attribute.split(":")) if attribute.include?(":")
    end
  end
end
```

And I include it this way in my generators:

```
class MyViewsGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  include Initializer
  initialize()
```

But when I call a generation, it fails with this error :

`Error: uninitialized constant MyViewsGenerator::Initializer.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use the methods from concern module as an instance methods in other classes, it should go into the `included` block.

To make methods from concern class methods, you would put them into `ClassMethods` module.

Since you call `initialize()` as a class method, you should actually put in inside `ClassMethods` module:

```
module Initializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do # instance methods goes here
    end

    module ClassMethods # class methods goes here
      # Initialize the generator accepting attributes as arguments
      def initialize(*args, &block)
       # ...
      end
    end

 end
```

By convention concerns modules are put into `models/concerns/` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I had to put the `initialize` method inside the `included` block.

Comment: I noticed my specs do not run any more after this update, do you have an idea how to include this concern into rspec file ? It gives the same error : `uninitialized constant MyViewsGenerator::Initializer`

Comment: @AlainANDRE, I'm afraid I've never faced such an issue - can't tell. I think you should try asking a question here on SO. Sorry